# R configuration for cysteine

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, erratum

I think my prof made a mistake. Shouldn't the answer be 1, 4 and 5 instead of 2 and 3?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the programmers did not make a mistake it seems that you are right - ChemDraw is on your side.

$\hskip.5in$[image: Bildbeschreibung und so]

Comment: I got 2 and 3 as the (R) isomer. 2 and 3 are the same isomer and I got a clockwise rotation, hence R, when numbering the priority of groups where H (the lowest priority) is facing away, or dashed line. I thought the order of priority would be NH2>COOH>CH2SH. Any ideas?

Comment: @LiamH It's NH2>COOH>CH2OH but S is more important than O because of it's higher atomic number and that's why NH2>CH2SH>COOH.

Comment: You beat me to my own correction PH13 haha >> Ah looks like I was wrong. Priority is NH2>CH2SH>COOH>H. Therefore I would have to agree with the above answer and 2/3 are actually an S configuration. Got confused for a minute there!